# how to set password for user signup with social accounts in django

Tags: django, django-allauth

i am using django-allauth. I want that when users signup with social accounts, redirect to set the password page. I do not know what to do. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset/update the password you can use `user.set_password(password)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean variable in your model indicating the completion of the signup process like is_completed, and force the user (redirection) to set password page if the variable is False